# handle state for uploading multiple upload react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload

i want to add data after uploading 1 image

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

const handleUpload = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files);
};

<input
  type="file"
  onChange={(e) => handleUpload(e)}
  ref={fileInputRef}
  multiple
/>
```

this was work if i select 2 or more files at once.
however i want to handle after choosing 1 image. user will be upload using the same input.

i have tried using method below and created error TypeError: file is not iterable

```
const handleUpload = (e) => {
    setFile([...files, e.target.files]);
};
```

or

```
const handleUpload = (e) => {
    let filesArray = file;
    if (file) {
      for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        filesArray.push(e.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
    setFile(filesArray);
};
```

do you guys have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first set the default value for file as an array in your `useState`, then while using the set method you need to use the `spread (...)` operator properly. This will resolve your error `TypeError: file is not iterable`

Below are the changes that you will need to perform.

```
export default function InputComponent() {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState([]);

  const handleUpload = (e) => {
    setFile([...file, ...e.target.files]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => handleUpload(e)} multiple /><br/><br/>
      <textarea value={file}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i already tried that but still giving the TypeError: file is not iterable because the file type.

Comment: I have made changes in handleUpload as wel, just check that function

Comment: thank you so much! sorry for my reply before. i forgot that i put setFile(null) in my useEffect. so it didn't work at first. thank you for your help